# Angular Material FlatTreeControl. Parent has added checkmark when all children removed

Tags: angular-material2, angular14

Angular Material FlatTreeControl.  The Parent node has checkmark added when all children removed.  This checkmark is added somewhere by AM which is incorrect as it should be unchecked.  If the user removes the checkmark then the checkmark tracking structure - SelectionModel - thinks the box has been checked causing a state mismatch.

Is there a solution for this?

My current workaround is to remove childless parent nodes; however, I need to keep the root node, so the problem still remains if all nodes are removed except for the root.